# Adding positive / negative Button to DialogFragment's Dialog

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment

I've already written a DialogFragment. Now I've realized that I want it to have a positive and a negative button just like an AlertDialog. How can I achieve such a thing while maintaining the code that I've written?

```
public class DoublePlayerChooser extends DialogFragment {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        

    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL,0);



}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setTitle("title")
            .setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        // do something...
                    }
                }
            )
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            )
            .create();
}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.doubleplayerchooser, container, false);
    getDialog().setTitle("Enter Players");

    firstPlayerPicker =  (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    firstPlayerPicker.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(final View v){

            callContactPicker(1);

        }       
    });

    secondPlayerPicker =  (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.ImageButton01);
    secondPlayerPicker.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(final View v){

            callContactPicker(2);

        }       
    });

    loadFromFile =  (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    loadFromFile.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(final View v){



        }       
    });

    firstTextfield =  (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    secondTextfield =  (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.EditText01);

    firstImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    secondImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);



    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

This is how I figured it out. I erased the onCreateView and altered the onCreateDialog.
This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257038/custom-layout-for-dialogfragment-oncreateview-vs-oncreatedialog) actually had the answer so all the credit should go there. I've just posted it just in case anyone bumps in this question first.

```
    @Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder b=  new  AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
    .setTitle("Enter Players")
    .setPositiveButton("OK",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                // do something...
            }
        }
    )
    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    );

    LayoutInflater i = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    View v = i.inflate(R.layout.doubleplayerchooser,null);

    firstPlayerPicker =  (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    firstPlayerPicker.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(final View v){

            callContactPicker(1);

        }       
    });

    secondPlayerPicker =  (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.ImageButton01);
    secondPlayerPicker.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(final View v){

            callContactPicker(2);

        }       
    });

    loadFromFile =  (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    loadFromFile.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(final View v){



        }       
    });

    firstTextfield =  (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    secondTextfield =  (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.EditText01);

    firstImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    secondImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);


    b.setView(v);
    return b.create();
}
```

Comment: It would be much clearer if content view's still created within `onCreateView(LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()),null,savedInstance)`.

Answer (score 7):

You have to **override the DialogFragments onCreateDialog(...) method:**

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setTitle("title")
            .setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        // do something...
                    }
                }
            )
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            )
            .create();
}
```

Taken from here: [Android: disable DialogFragment OK/Cancel buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912124/android-disable-dialogfragment-ok-cancel-buttons)

According to the error message you are getting ("request feature must be called...") I would recommend:

> **Don't call setContentView() before requestFeature()** in your Activity or wherever it is you are calling it.

Furthermore:

> Dont call **setStyle(...)** inside the onCreate().

Call it where you create your Fragment.

```
YourDialogFragment f = new YourDialogFragment(Context);
f.setStyle(...);
// and so on ...
```

Comment: i've done so but i get an exception request feature must be called before adding content android

Comment: Then please post some code of yours, and see my updated answer.

Comment: When i deleted the onCreateView it run without errors.if this helps you

Comment: onCreateView is already posted. setStyle is no mine its for the API.I've deleted the setStyle and it didn't work.

Comment: Sorry but your onCreateView() method is not posted. Only the onCreate() method.

Comment: I think it is..Did you scroll?

Comment: Lol, I was too stupid to scroll :) - Anyways, I think your error is related to setStyle(...) see my updated answer please.

Comment: Sorry just noticed now i get this exception requestFeature() must be called before adding content

Answer (score 4):

The clearest way.

```
// Your own onCreate_Dialog_View method
public View onCreateDialogView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container); // inflate here
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    // do something with 'view'
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // setup dialog: buttons, title etc
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setTitle(R.string.dialog_fragment_author_title)
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_fragment_author_close,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
            );

    // call default fragment methods and set view for dialog
    View view = onCreateDialogView(getActivity().getLayoutInflater(), null, null);
    onViewCreated(view, null);
    dialogBuilder.setView(view);

    return dialogBuilder.create();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To add action buttons call the [`setPositiveButton()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setPositiveButton%28int,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener%29) and [`setNegativeButton()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setNegativeButton%28int,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener%29) methods:

```
public class FireMissilesDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_fire_missiles)
           .setPositiveButton(R.string.fire, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // FIRE ZE MISSILES!
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // User cancelled the dialog
               }
           });
    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
    return builder.create();
}
}
```

More information about DialogFragment [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingButtons).

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit old but lately I've been overriding `onCreateView` when extending `AppCompatDialogFragment`. Just put your own buttons in the same layout you return in `onCreateView` - use styles like `@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless`.

You get the added bonus of controlling the Dialog self-dismissing when an action button is clicked, especially since these custom views sometimes have required inputs and you want to block the auto-close of the Dialog when a button is clicked.

Using a custom view in `onCreateDialog` has always felt dirty because you're inflating it with no container. Google tried making the API a bit nicer with the new v7 `AlertDialog.Builder` method `setView(int layoutResId)`, but you can't call `findViewById` then.

You should be adding a Theme like this in your styles.xml:

```
<style name="AlertDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/material_light_blue_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/material_light_blue_800</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/material_light_blue_a400</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/material_light_blue_500</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/material_light_blue_600</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/material_light_blue_a100</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/material_light_blue_a100</item>
</style>
```

You must override `onCreateDialog` in your DialogFragment to return `new AppCompatDialog(getActivity(), R.style.AlertDialog)` as well.